# The animation that is embeding in the slideshow runs just one time

Tags: jquery, html, animation, slideshow

I have designed a slide show which the first slide is an animation (designed by photoshop and exported to html) and the other slides are simple jpg files. So I have to devote different show times to first slide comparing to others.
I am doing this using following code:

js is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
               $('#slideshow_2').cycle({
                    fx: 'fade',     
                    speed:  'fast', 
                    timeoutFn: function(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
                        return parseInt($(opts.elements[opts.currSlide]).attr("data-duration"))* 1000;
                    },
                    pager: '.slides  .slideshow_paging', 
                    before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement) {
                        var data = $('.data', $(nextSlideElement)).html();
                        $('.slides  .slideshow_box').stop(true, true).animate({ bottom:'-110px'}, 400, function(){
                            $('.slides  .slideshow_box .data').html(data);
                        });
                        $('.slides  .slideshow_box').delay(100).animate({ bottom:'0'}, 400);
                    }
                });

                $('a[href="#"]').click(function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault(); // for this demo disable all links that point to "#"
                });             
            });         
        </script>
```

html is:

```
 <div class="slides">
                <div class="slideshow_paging"></div>
                <div class="slideshow_box">
                    <div class="data"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="container"><div class="timer"></div></div>
                <div id="slideshow_2" class="slideshow">

                        <img data-duration="14" src="images/animation.gif" style="width:100%;height:350px"/>

                        <img data-duration="5" src="images/translation2.jpg" style="width:100%;height:350px"/>

                        <img data-duration="5" src="images/translation3.jpg" style="width:100%;height:350px"/>

                        <img data-duration="5" src="images/translation4.jpg" style="width:100%;height:350px"/>

                </div>
            </div>
```

The output is great on first run of slideshow. I mean the animation embeded in the first slide is showing well when I enter the page for the first time or refresh it. But when slideshow starts repeating and moving in a loop, the animation in the first slide doesn't work anymore and just an image of it is shown.

I have tried adding and omminting $(function() ... but it doesn't help.

Comment: When you look at the animated gif alone in the browser (without the html, just load the image), does it loop? You have to set it in the gif.

Comment: I have made an animation file in photoshop and saved it using 'save for web and devices' tool. It was saved as gif format automatically. And Yes it works fine in the web page for the first time but not for other rounds.

Comment: photoshop defaults animated gifs to 'once' when you want 'forever'. Check to make sure it's set to forever either in photoshop or by going to http://yoursite/path/to/images/animation.gif

Comment: yes it is set to forever but it doesn't help.

Comment: This is scenario:   1- I have animation file on slide 1.   2- Imagine slide 1 is running and it is not finished yet.   3-If e.g. I click pager part to go to slide 3 and then back to slide 1 again, slide one continues to run from its previous state.  5- I need each time slide 1 is showing, it is shown from first, not from previous part.